# How do I create a nested list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to create a nested hierarchical list so that for each task I can have subtasks like in iOS reminders app:

[image]

First attempt was to embed another list inside a list cell.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            List {
              Text("Hello, World!")

            }

        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
```

But it didn't work out.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you think it should be List in List... Such visual representation can be generated using only one list and it will have native look & feel.

Here is just a demo (w/o UI tuning and logic of showing/hiding sections, that is out of topic), but the idea should be clear

[image: nested list]

```
struct ItemRow: View {
    let category: Bool
    let text: String
    
    init(_ text: String, isCategory: Bool = false) {
        self.category = isCategory
        self.text = text
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Circle().stroke() // this can be custom control
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // handle tap here
                }
            if category {
                Text(self.text).bold()
            } else {
                Text(self.text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TestNestedLists: View {
    var body: some View {
        List { // next pattern easily wrapped with ForEach
            ItemRow("Category", isCategory: true) // this can be section's header
            Section {
                ItemRow("Item 1")
                ItemRow("Item 2")
                ItemRow("Item 3")
            }.padding(.leading, 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not create a collapsable list though

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is fine if you want a static sub-list, but if you're looking for a collapsible sub-list, you should use a DisclosureGroup, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List {
            DisclosureGroup {
                Text("Also get avocados")
            } label: {
                Text("Grab a cucumber and limes from Whole Foods")
            }
            Text("Buy Justin a gift for his 6th birthday")
            Text("Tattoo consultation")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Reminders")
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Please remember that the ordering of the answers is dynamic on StackOverflow and "the first answer" may be a different one at any time.

Answer (score 2):

Place one list inside another, like this small example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("External List")
            List {
                Text("Internal List")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It results in this:
[Result Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POlNC.png)

I was testing and found that the error occurs when the style of the inner list is any grouped style (.grouped, .insetGrouped or the new .sidebar).

In contrast, if the internal list has any non-grouped style (.inset or .plain) it works correctly.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("External List")
            List {
                Text("Internal List")
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
        }
    }
}
```

It results in this:
[Result OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebMPw.png)

Beyond this, as mentioned in many places, you should not use nested lists. You should try to resolve with VStack or ForEach.

Comment: I think that your last comment gives the best practice hint: "you should not use nested lists. You should try to resolve with VStack or ForEach"

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard, but you have to manually add some frame.

```
        struct SwiftUIViewList: View {
            var body: some View {
                    List {
                      Text("Hello, World!")
                      Text("Hello, World!")
                }
            }
        }

        struct SwiftUIView: View {
            var body: some View {

                List {

                   Text("item1")
                    SwiftUIViewList().frame(height: 100)
                   Text("item3")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This might work. But it certainly is not the recommended way i guess.