# Multiple level List in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working with a project in SwiftUI. I want to create something like,

[image]

The code I'm using currently:

**`TaskListView`**

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    var tasks: [Task] = Task.all()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.tasks) {task in
                TaskView(task: task)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`TaskView`**

```
struct TaskView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(task.name)
            .font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 14))
            
            //Here.................
            if !task.subtasks.isEmpty {
                Section {
                    ForEach(task.subtasks) {subtask in
                        TDTaskView(task: subtask)
                    }
                }.padding(.leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Task`** model:

```
class Task: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var isCompleted: Bool = false
    var subtasks = [Task]()
    
    init(name: String, isCompleted: Bool = false, subtasks: [Task] = [Task]()) {
        self.name = name
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
        self.subtasks = subtasks
    }
}
```

The way I'm trying to implement nested `List` is now working properly on selection. Am I implementing it wrongly?

Comment: You need to use sections. This [SwiftUI - nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58883690/12299030) can be helpful.

Comment: I tried this already. But the issue is I don't know the nesting levels. In the link example, its just 2 level nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to create items recursively:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var tasks: [Task] = Task.all()

    var body: some View {
        List {
            TaskListView(tasks: tasks)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TaskListView: View {
    var tasks: [Task]

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(tasks, id: \.id) { task in
            TaskView(task: task)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TaskView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Circle().stroke() // replace with a custom control
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(task.name)
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 14))
                Spacer()
            }
            if !task.subtasks.isEmpty {
                TaskListView(tasks: task.subtasks)
                    .padding(.leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, I'd say change only two things.

First, change the VStack to a Group, so that the individual "tasks" will be managed by the List:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(task.name)
        .font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 14))
```

---

```
var body: some View {
    Group {
        Text(task.name)
        .font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 14))
```

Second, change your `TDTaskView` to `TaskView`, so the code you already wrote will recursively build out your task list:

```
        if !task.subtasks.isEmpty {
            Section {
                ForEach(task.subtasks) {subtask in
                    TDTaskView(task: subtask)
                }
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
```

---

```
        if !task.subtasks.isEmpty {
            Section {
                ForEach(task.subtasks) {subtask in
                    TaskView(task: subtask)
                }
            }.padding(.leading)
        }
```

---

### Edit

Here's the full working code (very close to your original code):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var tasks: [Task] = [Task(name: "thing"), Task(name: "more work"), Task(name: "Huge job", isCompleted: false, subtasks: [Task(name: "smaller job"), Task(name: "sorta small job")])]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.tasks) {task in
                TaskView(task: task)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TaskView: View {
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text(task.name)
                .font(.custom("Avenir Next Regular", size: 14))
            
            //Here.................
            if !task.subtasks.isEmpty {
                Section {
                    ForEach(task.subtasks) {subtask in
                        TaskView(task: subtask)
                    }
                }.padding(.leading)
            }
        }
    }
}


class Task: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    @Published var isCompleted: Bool = false
    var subtasks = [Task]()
    
    init(name: String, isCompleted: Bool = false, subtasks: [Task] = [Task]()) {
        self.name = name
        self.isCompleted = isCompleted
        self.subtasks = subtasks
    }
}
```