# List to display data from server in swiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swiftui

Im fetching data from server and I need to show it like displayed in this site
[SwiftUI - nested list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882673/swiftui-nested-list)

Data from server is

```
  "OptionsListByItemId": [
        {
         "Choices": [
           {
             "ChoiceId": 1284226,
              "ChoiceName": "Hot",
            },
            { 
              "ChoiceId": 1284227,
              "ChoiceName": "Cool",
            }
          ],
          "OptionId": 187472,
          "OptionName": "Temperature"
      },
    
      { 
       "Choices": [
           {
             "ChoiceId": 1284223,
              "ChoiceName": "61%",
            },
            { 
              "ChoiceId": 1284224,
              "ChoiceName": "70%",
            }
          ],
          "OptionId": 187473,
          "OptionName": "Humidity"
 ]
}
```

My model is like

```
struct OptionsandChoices : Decodable , Identifiable{
    
    var id: String{OptionName}
    var OptionName: String!
    var OptionId: Int
    var Choices : [ChoiseList]
    
}

struct OptionsandChoiceList: Decodable{
    
    var OptionsListByItemId:[OptionsandChoices]  
}
struct ChoiseList: Decodable {
    var ChoiceName: String!
    var ChoiceId: Int
}
```

ViewModel is

```
class ItemChoiceViewModel : ObservableObject{
 @Published var OpnChoice: OptionsandChoiceList = OptionsandChoiceList(OptionsListByItemId: [])
 // fetching data from server 
}
```

My swiftUI view like

```
struct ItemView: View {
 var OpnChoice = OptionsandChoiceList(OptionsListByItemId: [])
 @ObservedObject var choicevwModel = ChoiceViewModel()

struct Optionspage: View {
   var body: some View {
   List(choicevwModel.OpnChoice.OptionsListByItemId) {opn in 
       Text(opn.OptionName)
   }
}
```

Im unable to use ChoiceName in List

How can I able to get choiceName in each row below OptionName like in the link I gave

List Should be displayed like

```
 Temperature 
    Hot 
    Cold 
 
 Humidity
    61%
    70%
```

Currently I get in two rows

```
 Temperature
 Humidity
```

Comment: Iterate through the `Choices`

Comment: @loremipsum If I give Text(opn.Choices.ChoiceName) it gives me error "Value of type '[ChoiseList]' has no member 'ChoiceName' "

Comment: Iterate, use a loop of some kind

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is located in `Choices`. To get it's value write following:

```
opn.Choices[yourIndex].OptionName
```

Also, if you want to use `@ObservedObject` make your `OptionsandChoiceList` class instead of struct and make it conform `ObservableObject` protocol. Finally, declare `@Published` property there.

```
final class OptionsandChoiceList: ObservableObject, Decodable {
    @Published var OptionsListByItemId: OptionsandChoices = []  
}
```

Comment: the choice of names is so bad that even the code writer can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: I totally agree, naming is awful.

Comment: If I give Text(opn.Choices.ChoiceName) it gives me error "Value of type '[ChoiseList]' has no member 'ChoiceName' "

Comment: @RomaKavinskyi I have written like what u said it gives me an error. Though ChoiceList has ChoiceName it shows error

Comment: How's your progress so far?